Generate A5 and B5 from the same source, preserving the layout
I use memoir for a children's book with illustrations. The document size is A5, because A4 printers are widely available and can be used to print the PDF as a booklet at home.
Now I would like to produce a B5 version for use with online publishing services; with a bigger page the text can be larger (major plus for kids) while the layout remains roughly the same. However, this would make printing at home more difficult, because mainstream household printers are typically A4.
I am looking for an approach to use the same source code for both sizes, without resorting to if/then/else statements and hardcoded values for each paper size.
I understand that constructions like \hspace{1cm}\includegraphics[width=10cm]{images/sad-faces} must be rewritten to use \paperwidth and a coefficient. I also have illustrations that cover the entire page leaving no margins; since A5 and B5 have different proportions - I'd have to crop these illustrations.
However, I am not sure how to deal with text - I want it to be physically bigger on B5, but how to ensure that line widths are the same and that the paragraphs don't "spill over" to the next page? I have a lot of places where the text is fine-tuned to the image, if the text moves too far from its ideal location on the page - the layout is broken.
One example:

Another one:

As an alternative, if such size-agnostic approaches are not easy to accomplish, perhaps I can change the way I position images on the page, to make the layout more resilient to changes?

I would create an A5 PDF, then use pdfpages to copy it to B5.  (or vice verses).

This is an elegant solution - I tried it and it works. If you turn your comment into an answer - I'll mark it as the accepted solution. Thank you for the hint, I appreciate your help.

I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in the comments.

It wa late,  I was tired.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=176mm, paperheight=250mm}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{test5}% replace with A5 PDF
\end{document}

